# не работает регулярное выражение js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему возвращает null?

```
let phone = '485462001312'
let pattern = '/^\d{3}\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\$/';
let test = phone.match(pattern);
if(test){
alert('ok');
}else {
alert('null');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас две ошибки:

1. В качестве regex вы присваиваете строку (не нужны там одинарные кавычки)
2. Экранировать символ конца строки в regex не надо.

Вот ваш исправленный пример:

```
'485462001312'.match(/^\d{3}\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}$/)
```

или его можно сократить до

```
'485462001312'.match(/^\d{12}$/)
```

[RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)